# How to save JSON event data from Fullcalendar in iCalendar format

Tags: php, fullcalendar, icalendar

I am using Fullcalendar to display an event feed and need to implement an iCalendar export feature. If I have the calendar events as an array of json events, is there a way to convert this json array to either:
(1) a .ics file or

(2) a .xml file in xcal format?

Comment: Someone must know of a way to get fullCalendar events in ical format. Any point in the right direction will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the google calendar plugin of fullcalendar : it provides import from google calendar xml format to json. this could be a good starting point for going backwards.